# Filter out only the array by keeping one instance of the value if its consecutive element is a duplicate

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any cleaner way in javascript, by which I can filter out the next duplicate element in an array (by just keeping one value in it)?

For eg: if `let arr=[1,2,1,1,3,3,3,4,2,2,1,3]`, I should get something like `[1,2,1,3,4,2,1,3]`, one way is to write a for loop and filter it out using the `for` loop

```
let arr=[1,2,1,1,3,3,3,4,2,2,1,3];    
let newArr =[];
let n = arr.length;
for(let i=0; i<n-1;i++){
    if(arr[i]!=arr[i+1]){
       newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
 }
 console.log(newArr);
```

**NOTE: Its not removing the duplicate elements in the array, but keeping one instance of the value if its consecutive element is a duplicate.** 

But, is there any easier and cleaner way to do it in Javascript?

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean by 'next duplicate'? I would expect `[3, 3, 3]` to become `[3, 3]` if you were only removing the next duplicate.

Comment: Near duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array Just store most recent instead of all.

Comment: If its `[3,3,3]` then it should become just `[3]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` for this. This will only remove dupes that are consecutive. The first element is automatically included, then it just checks if the current one is different than the previous one. If so, it pushes into the result.

```js
let arr=[1,2,1,1,3,3,3,4,2,2,1,3]
let res = arr.reduce((a,c,i,ar) => {
    if (i == 0 || ar[i] !== ar[i-1]) a.push(c)
    return a
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

You can also use `filter()`, which is probably a cleaner solution:

```js
let arr=[1,2,1,1,3,3,3,4,2,2,1,3]
let res = arr.filter((c,i,ar) => i == 0 || ar[i] !== ar[i-1])
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks Meyer, this is what I was looking for. I am sorry if I confused you with the way of my asking question.

Comment: Nice solution with filter

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.reduce(((a,c) => (a[a.length-1] === c) ? a : a.concat(c)), []);
```